# change the text of the button on click using angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How I can change the text of the button on click of the button.

Here it is what I have tried.

HTML:

```
<button ng-click="toggle = !toggle">Toggle!</button>
<div class="box on" ng-show="toggle" ng-animate="'box'">On</div>
```

JS:

```
function MainController($scope) {
  $scope.toggle = true;
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think, using a watch of `toggle` should do it

```
<button ng-click="toggle = !toggle">{{toggleText}}</button>
<div class="box on" ng-show="toggle" ng-animate="'box'">On</div>
```

then

```
app.controller('AppController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.toggle = true;

    $scope.$watch('toggle', function(){
        $scope.toggleText = $scope.toggle ? 'Toggle!' : 'some text';
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Ljrpd/)

Answer (score 29):

Or, keep all the content in your HTML, rather than defining the button text in the controller, if you prefer:

```
<button ng-click="toggle = !toggle">
    <span ng-show="toggle">Toggle to Off</span>
    <span ng-hide="toggle">Toggle to On</span>
</button>
<div class="box on" ng-show="toggle" ng-animate="'box'">On</div>
```

Comment: In my opinion, this is probably the more "correct" way to do it, since a text change is a purely user interface related thing. It's best practice to try and keep any strictly UI-related code outside of your controller, preferably in the template, or in a directive.

Answer (score 9):

I would use neither watch nor ng-show because of their performance. That is simple as this:

```
app.controller('AppController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.toggle = true;
})

<button ng-click="toggle = !toggle">{{toggle && 'Toggle!' || 'some text'}}</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution, supporting translation:

HTML:

```
<span class="togglebutton">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="{{myApp.enabled}}"
               ng-model="myApp.enabled" ng-click="toggleEnabled()">
        <span translate="{{myApp.enableCaption}}">Is Enabled?</span>
    </label>
</span>
```

JS - Controller:

```
$scope.toggleEnabled = function() {
    $scope.myApp.enableCaption = $scope.myApp.enabled ? 'global.enabled' : 'global.disabled';
};
```

where `global.enabled` and `global.disabled` refer to i18n JSON translations. You also need to initialize `enableCaption` in JS, in place where you create an empty object.

Answer (score 0):

Existing answers are good, but here's a somewhat more refined solution using a ternary to select the appropriate text depending on whether the toggle is on or off. Additionally, `toggle` is a somewhat unclear variable name since it's not clear what states "true" or "false" correspond to. Perhaps `toggleOn` or simply `on` is better.

```js
angular.module("exampleApp", [])
  .controller("toggleCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.on = true;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.8.2/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="exampleApp" ng-controller="toggleCtrl">
  <button ng-click="on = !on">
    Toggle {{on ? "off" : "on"}}
  </button>
  <div ng-show="on">On</div>
</div>
```